# RenderForm y Tree categories, ¿cómo recuperar las categorías seleccionadas?

Tags: prestashop

Saludos! En mi módulo prestashop tengo un renderForm con un input categories, me funciona bien pero no encuentro la manera de validarlo y recuperar las categorías que ha seleccionado el usuario.

```
array(
               'type'  => 'categories',
               'label' => $this->l('Root category'),
               'name'  => 'CHECK_CATEGORIES',
               'tree'  => array(
                            'id' => 'id_root_category',
                          )
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

En la funcion _postProcess() o getContent(), donde hagas el if al submit, pon lo siguiente(si no lo tienes), con esto guardamos los valores:

```
Configuration::updateValue('CHECK_CATEGORIES', serialize(Tools::getValue('id_root_category')));
```

Luego pon el array asi:

```
array(
    'type'  => 'categories',
    'label' => $this->l('Root category'),
    'name'  => 'CHECK_CATEGORIES',
    'tree' => array(
        'id' => 'id_root_category',
        'use_checkbox' => true,
        'selected_categories' => unserialize(Configuration::get('CHECK_CATEGORIES')))
```

Suerte!!